# How do you prevent "break" between "a:before" and "a" elements

Tags: html, css

If you are inserting something at the start of links (an icon, or whatever), how do you prevent the browser inserting a line break between the icon and the text when the link wraps at the edge of the page. i.e. With this:

```
a:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f101\00a0";
    font-size: 0.9em;
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
```

}

Currently if you resize the browser window, html like this:

```
<p>
This is some example text where my link
<a href="...">link</a> is having its icon on the
previous line.
</p>
```

may render something like this:

> This is some example text where my link %
>   *link* is having its icon on the previous line.

Comment: running your code in a JSFiddle, it works as expected, no line break... http://jsfiddle.net/A4VcV/

Comment: same here! no line break...

Comment: It breaks for me in Mac Safari, Mac Chrome, and iPhone. Perhaps there is a minor misunderstanding. It breaks when the link hits the end of the screen and wraps. (you have to adjust your browser window width to cause it to break)

Comment: Firefox (mac) also allows the insertion of the line break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `white-space:nowrap` to your `a` element (not the `:before` psuedoelement)

However keep in mind that this may cause problems if the text cannot actually fit on one line in the window.

i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/A4VcV/4/

Comment: This does prevent the break, but as you point out, it does mean long links may become problematic. May be the best answer...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `display:inline-block;`

http://jsfiddle.net/ApaYP/

Tested on Mac Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The `display: inline-block;` is required, as it prevents the underline of the link slipping under the icon/image. This is the only method I have found successfully prevents the underline entering the `a:before`

Comment: @Jacob it doesn't seem to prevent the underline on my screen.

Comment: `display:inline-block;` does, on all main browsers on mac, pc, and iOS, remove the underline from the icon. We thoroughly tested for the underline issue already.

Comment: @Jacob you're correct, guess it was a caching problem cause I swear the underline was there 20 minutes ago :) Maybe just use jQuery for that...

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `position: absolute;` for this sort of thing. Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style media="all">
a {position: relative; padding-left: 1em;}
a:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f101\00a0";
    font-size: 0.9em;
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is some example text where my link <a href="...">link</a> is having its icon on the previous line.</p>

</body>
</html>
```